# Variable inside php preg_match

Tags: php

I know there are a couple of post duplication regarding this issue - but unfortunately i couldn't find any matching answer.

I'm trying to do replace the "field_name" with a variable

```
if(preg_match('/^field_name/', $key)){
}
```

So I've tried the following attempts - but didn't succeed...

```
if(preg_match('/^\['.$field_name.'\]/', $key)){}      

------------------------------------------------

if(preg_match('/$field_name/', $key)){}

------------------------------------------------

if(preg_match('/^[$field_name]/', $key)){}

------------------------------------------------

if(preg_match('/^{'. $field_name .'}$/', $key)){}
```

Comment: Either `'/^' . $field_name . '/'` or `"/^$field_name/"`. All the other song and dance you're adding there is useless. Also note that you might want to look at [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote).

Comment: Thanks - i know there is a lot of rubbish there - but... when you're desperate you do all you can...   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$field = 'test';

if(preg_match("/^$field/", 'test')){
  echo 'working';
}
```

Use double quotes to make sure that php parse the variable inside the string.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working is because in most cases you use the wrong syntax (quotes) to include a variable

You can't just place a variable inside single quotes, your correct code would be:

```
if(preg_match('/'.$field_name.'/', $key)){}
```

Comment: As a precaution, it is advisable to escape dynamic values before using it as a regular exception pattern.

`if (preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($field_name).'$/', $key)) {}`